# solar installation, going from enphase combiner box to the disconnect switch do I need to run a ground,

Tags: ground

The enphase inverters  output is 240v ac to the combiner box, 2wire. I am running 3 wire, 2 hot and one neutral from the combiner to the safety shut off switch, I need 120v at the combiner box.  Should I also run a Ground wire from the combiner box to the shut off switch

Answer (score 2):

There's no use whatsoever for neutral from the panel through the disconnect to the combiner, unless something *in the combiner box* needs neutral.

**Neutral is not ground**.  Anything you've seen that makes you think otherwise is a misinterpretation.  (we get a lot of that...)

Grounding is mandatory *[everywhere](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=do%20I%20need%20to%20ground%20solar%20panels&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)* as of 1965 NEC.  Three oddball exceptions were stamped out in 1996, 1999 and 2008.

Note that if you are using metal non-flex conduit, that is a valid grounding path and a ground wire is not also needed * ASTERISK.

* ASTERISK first, you're free to do it anyway, "belt and suspenders" lol. Second, it can help with conduit fill, because there's a glitch in the conduit fill rules where they're harsher on 2 wires than 3.  Adding the 3rd ground wire makes certain combinations possible, like two #6 THHN in 1/2" conduit - illegal without ground, legal with (provided the ground is reasonably small).